# Sublime Text 3: SublimeLinter: c disabled ("cppcheck" cannot be found)

Tags: c++, c, sublimetext3, cppcheck, sublimelinter

Hello I'm still getting this error: SublimeLinter: c disabled ("cppcheck" cannot be found)
even if I tried to install Google cpplint.
Here are my User settings:

```
{
"sublimelinter": "save-only",

"sublimelinter_syntax_map":
{
"Python Django": "python",
"Ruby on Rails": "ruby",
"C++": "c_cpplint",
"C": "c_cpplint"
},
"sublimelinter_executable_map":
{
"perl": "perl",
"php": "php",
"ruby": "rvm-auto-ruby",
"c_cpplint": "/Users/Nenor/cpplint.py"
},
}
```

I prefer if it will work with cppcheck. 
Running OS X 10.9, Sublime Text 3047

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the original SublimeLinter? I think it doesn't work with Sublime3 yet. See https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter3